# With out changing the order of "select:Option" how to make a specific option as selected by default in visual force <apex:seleList>?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Ape" itemValue="Ape"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Bat" itemValue="Bat"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Cat" itemValue="Cat"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Dog" itemValue="Dog"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Elephant" itemValue="Elephant"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here "Ape" is selected by default since it is the first option but With out changing the order of the apex:selectOption I want to make "Dog" as selected by default.

Please tell me how to achieve this without using Apex and without using script if possible
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without Apex and JavaScript? that's a lot of limitation and I don't know what's the point of the page, how are you going to use the value in any way.

You could always downgrade it all the way to pure HTML

```html
<apex:page>
    <select>
        <option>Ape</option>
        <option>Bat</option>
        <option>Cat</option>
        <option selected="true">Dog</option>
        <option>Elephant</option>
    </select>
</apex:page>
```